# What is the best big data solution for interactive queries of rows with up to 200 columns?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hbase, bigdata, apache-storm

We have a simple table such as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Name   | Attribute1 | Attribute2 | Attribute3 | ... | Attribute200 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Name1    | Value1     | Value2     | null       | ... | Value3       |
| Name2    | null       | Value4     | null       | ... | Value5       |
| Name3    | Value6     | null       | Value7     | ... | null         |
| ...                                                                  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But there could be up to hundreds of millions of rows/names.
The data will be populated every hour or so.

The goal is to get results for interactive queries on the data within a couple of seconds.

Most queries look like:

```
select count(*) from table
where Attribute1 = Value1 and Attribute3 = Value3 and Attribute113 = Value113;
```

The where clause contains arbitrary number of attribute name-value pairs.

I'm new in big data and wondering what the best option is in terms of data store (MySQL, HBase, Cassandra, etc) and processing engine (Hadoop, Drill, Storm, etc) for interactive queries like above.

Comment: Your description of what type of queries you want to perform is that you want to be able to perform exponentially many different queries (2 ^ 200 in your example). If that's the case, I believe I don't think you're going to find any solution cheaper than scanning your table and counting the number of rows that match your predicate.

If you can restrict the possible queries somehow or provide more context, maybe I have a better solution for you.

Comment: I believe the number of possible queries will be much less than the worst case scenario. But it's up to the users to compose them, so I don't have a control over how many predicates they're going to include. In case of scanning the whole table, what's the best solution?

Comment: I'm less familiar with Cassandra, so I'll talk in terms of HBase. If you're going to try simply scanning all the rows, you can do a simple HBase scan with filter (http://hbase.apache.org/book/thrift.html) to stream back to your HBase client (say a thrift client) the set of rows that match your predicate, then count those. What language will you be interfacing with the database (HBase?) from? Again, I can give a "real" answer with more details about the environment.

Comment: Also, Hadoop is a natural fit for this sort of query and integrates very nicely with HBase. So my comment about using a Thrift client isn't quite right. You would want to do this by writing a Hadoop job that processes row-ranges of the HBase table directly.

Comment: I'm using Java. Hadoop seems suitable for this, but from what I read, it's intended for batch processing (which might take few minutes to few hours).

Comment: Check out Hadoop Streaming. It can eliminate the Hadoop job startup time so that you can potentially get the few-second query times you're looking for. [hadoopy](https://github.com/bwhite/hadoopy) is a nice tool authored by a friend of mine that makes this very easy to do, but it's for python.

Comment: @TimothyShields Hadoop streaming is just a scripting interface by forking a new process inside the normal task workflow. This is neither faster nor slower than the normal batch oriented nature of Hadoop.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Oh, I'm getting the Hadoop streaming functionality confused with the hadoopy functionality. It's hadoopy which has the "drastically-reduced startup time" feature I'm talking about. So forget about that comment...

Comment: @TimothyShields still, `Hadoopy` is just a `Cython` wrapper, means that the process itself starts faster than the usually python interpreter. But that does not neglect scheduling and starting overhead of the java tasks itself. Sorry for the nitpicking, but there is no way to get faster in Hadoop M/R than batch processing.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Nope, hadoopy has a feature called "freezing" a certain job. It basically means that all of the hadoop mappers, reducers, etc are already loaded along with the JVM and are simply waiting for "the go signal".  The total combined system time per job for your entire cluster isn't really reduced, but the *latency* is reduced. This is because you can have the "frozen" jobs already waiting ahead of the requests to start them. But I think this outside the scope of the OP's question anyway...

Comment: @TimothyShields this solves the cold-start problem (was first proposed in the Google Dremel paper). Thanks for the addition.

Comment: I am no expert but that seems a good job for couchdb's views. One of the main features of it is incremental MapReduce using design documents views. Or if you feel in an experimental mood why not look at NewSQL solutions (most are very "immature" yet though).

Comment: @le_douard I believe incremental MapReduce is not appropriate here because of the practically unbounded number of possible queries. Incremental MapReduce is appropriate when there is some predetermined set of queries you are interested in answering (e.g. word count of a set of documents), but where the data is constantly being updated.

Comment: @TimothyShields I agree with you, we don't have prior knowledge of number of predicates in the query, so we can't use predefined views. But even if we know the predicates upfront, it's possible that the amount of data updated is so big that it would take a lot of time also to do incremental MapReduce.

Comment: if you looking for cassandra then probably i can suggest you some thing

Comment: Have you considered looking at using Impala?  You would be able to support your SQL queries (most of them), in addition to getting very fast speeds (faster than Hive over HDFS) using Hadoop.  Downside might be the memory requirements... I believe the typical Impala environments have lots of memory to do the JOINs, etc, with the data.  See:  http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/cloudera-impala-real-time-queries-in-apache-hadoop-for-real/

Answer (score 0):

A columnar DB like Vertica (closed source) or MonetDB (open source - but I haven't used it) will handle queries like the ones you mentioned efficiently. In 50000 feet view the reasons for this is that they stores each column separately and thus doesn't read any unneeded columns when they need to query data - for your example 3 attributes will be read and the other 197 won't be

Answer (score 0):

Playorm for Cassandra provide a decent support for SQL including Joins. Read more at http://buffalosw.com/wiki/SJQL-Support/ and for examples see http://buffalosw.com/wiki/Command-Line-Tool/